# (SOLVED) How to recover data from Android ... /sdCard/ ... /Downloads on Xiaomi Mi5 MIUI8 (Android 6 Marshmallow)

Tags: root-access, data-recovery, twrp, mtp, usb-mass-storage

**UPDATE: 2018/06/27, bootloader implies wipe and it is a dead end for Data Recovery, mount as USB Mass Storage implies root to change settings, and for Mi5 or MIUI 8 this implies flashing ROM (dead end too as implies Data overwritten) so the only method I found is [this](http://howtorecover.me/data-recovery-internal-storage-android-phone-guide) (if the device is functional) then with the RAW partition dump recover files is easy**

(LEGACY-post as is solved)

I have a problem I want to solve:

Notice: This is a specific problem, please try to advice on that matter (see complications at the bottom), any help and clarification will be very appreciated.

Fact:

- I deleted by mistake files on path .. sdCard / .. / Downloads (internal memory)
- Seconds after mistaken-deletion, I shut off the device, to prevent overwriting.

Specs:
Smartphone
Xiaomi Mi5 Miui 8 (Android 6 Marshmallow)
Non-rooted
Stock-recovery

WiP (workflow):

- I notice about USB Mass Storage instead MTP (as key feature to connect device to PC) (and use some kind of recovery app like (Recuva or R-Studio (r-tt.com))
- But I don't know how to activate that (Mass Storage) on my specific device and MIUI (Android version)

Another choice is create a image dump from custom recovery (TWRP) but how to install custom recovery...
... without changing the stock ROM,
... I saw unlocked bootloader is needed

Complications:

- How to recover data from (internal sdCard, eMMc | UFS), without overwriting data.
- How to root (if needed) without the changing of custom-ROM (if it is possible), on this specific device.
- How to install custom recovery (bootloader unlocked is needed) to make a "raw image dump" exact byte-by-byte from the recovery ( isolated image dump, to work with IT Forensics tools)
- Xiaomi Mi5 (how to root, methods, if it is needed), and how to install custom recovery, TWRP (bootloader unlocking etc)
- Thanks in advance, first post here (a reader for years), I hope some people lead the way ^^, I want to learn.

Xiaomi Mi5 particularities: (more info-sources will be appreciated)

- root methods (without ROM-changing)
- TWRP recovery (stock ROM if possible) => create internal memory RAW image) to work with.
- Bootloader-unlock methods and process

Comment: Please focus on one question (you are asking 4 of them)- one question at a time will help you get quicker answers and is best suited for this site. There is nothing stopping you from asking multiple questions !

Comment: While waiting for answers, please take a look at our [data-recovery tag-wiki](/tags/data-recovery/info) and the questions using that tag. As you correctly assumed, using a custom recovery requires to unlock the bootloader, which usually implies a factory-reset. There might be a [tag:rooting] method that works without; as @beeshyams pointed out, that would be a separate question ("How to root the Xiaomi Mi5"); our [rooting index](/q/1184/16575) doesn't have that yet and neither could I find that question on our site, which means you should go for it.

Comment: You are right @beeshyams (my mistake, as newbie) I will create separated questions to isolate the problems, then link that to the "main problem".

Comment: Thanks for suggestions @Izzy, I will (Data Recovery tag and related for clarification), as you said I want to avoid "as maximum as possible" writings on internal-memory, avoiding "factory reset" or wipes as possible. After TWRP is installed, I could create a NANDroid backup of specific partitions (raw images) then set them read only and mounted on PC I could use some IT-Forensics apps... to recover deleted (non-overwrited files)

Comment: If your device is unlocked, you could even use TWRP without installing it: `fastboot boot twrp.img` would directly boot it without any modifications to the device.

Comment: Thanks, that is good idea, the problem, device has locked-bootloader, now I am searching for an easy and minimal method to unlock bootloader (without flashing ROM, wipes, factory reset)... Other devices have easy methods to unlock bootloader, I will create a question as how to unlock bootloader methods in this particular device, searching for the best method, less agressive with internal memory writings.

Comment: Flashing TWRP or boot via FastBoot with TWRP image It is technically impossible with a locked bootloader? There is nothing like a hack or something? ... If not I could backup partitions via ADB? If unlocking-Bootloader is the key, I need to find a proper method (official, unofficial or new back) thanks for answers.