# (SOLVED) How (methods) to unlock Bootloader on own Xiaomi Mi5 MIUI8 (Data Recovery context)

Tags: data-recovery, twrp, bootloader, xiaomi, miui

**UPDATE: 2018/06/27, bootloader implies wipe and it is a dead end for Data Recovery, mount as USB Mass Storage implies root to change settings, and for Mi5 or MIUI 8 this implies flashing ROM (dead end too as implies Data overwritten) so the only method I found is [this](http://howtorecover.me/data-recovery-internal-storage-android-phone-guide) (if the device is functional)** then with the RAW partition dump recover files is easy

(LEGACY-post, solved)

I have a problem (objective: Data Recovery)

To install TWRP (it seems, I need, explicitly unlocked-bootloader)
To unlock bootloader I researched and saw some methods:

- Official method (tedious and If I understand it correctly, implies flashing some Developer-ROM, and "shit") (I want avoid that)
- non-Official methods (a group of queries, I don't find too much clear methods) (BTW quality-posts on XDA-Developers have seen better days :'(

The thing is, I don't want to re-flash some ROM (as I want minimize writings for Data Recovery)

How to check if bootloader is effective-locked ?

Question: I need ways to unlock-Bootloader in this Xiaomi Mi5 device with MIUi 8 global stock (methods, more than one or two, and then I will research about it)

(This is not a trivial-question as in this particular-case:

Logic => unlocking-Bootloader <=> install TWRP to backup partitions (do Data Recovery with them, mounted on PC)

I don't know, I don't have (the Knowledge) to do some hack, but I think this has to have proper-solution.

The objective is here:
[How to recover Data from Android .. sdCard / .. Downloads on Xiaomi Mi5 MIUI 8](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/188213/how-to-recover-data-from-android-sdcard-downloads-on-xiaomi-mi5-miui8)

Therefore both questions are related to each other...

Any help will be very appreciated (final objective is Data Recovery, but I want to try software, before "JTAG dump" etc (and implications of that process)

Comment: No unlocking method will preserve data, that's an anti-theft measure. Basically your position right now is the same as any thief holding a phone stolen from somewhere else, trying to obtain data inside. Also, you're better off rewording the question so it prioritizes the "data recovery" aspect rather than the "BL unlocking" aspect.

Comment: @beeshyams, I am working on it (official MIUI forums), thanks for answer

Comment: @beeshyams Mi A1 isn't quite a Mi device so to speak...

Comment: @AndyYan: That is a "theory" (statement) the excuse of anti-theft is not for me (sorry) BTW, if Xiaomi wants I have probe it is "my phone" don't worry about that. But I don't trust Xiaomi either to recover my data. There is more on Data Recovery and IT-Forensics beyond the excuse of "capped-control" of our own devices (encryption solve things, managed by own user of course). About rewording I agree, but the thing is there is main question open related to that.

Comment: @AndyYan: The real theft (usually) is "inside" the OS, that is the tragedy. (Thanks for answer BTW), there are methods to verify identity and property of devices (that implies serious support by the OEM), and they have procedures to get the data (If they want) And I want now. (When the government wants, think about your "anti theft" measure. Warranty of "control your own data", that is the important key here. The "bad guys" argument (always is), that is another matter.

Comment: (BTW) My comments have zero-acrimony (I don't know if that is a common or proper word :D), English is not my mother language. I value my data (that is all) zero intention of "roughness" I understand the "bad guys" argument (and why you said it) @AndyYan, fortunately is not that case.

Comment: I roughly get your idea. I believe manufacturers do have access to the data without unlocking BL, but that would require hardware-level access (special connectors, cables, PC-side tools, etc.). Do note that even to reflash a semi-bricked Mi device you'll need a specialized cable to access the emergency download mode. Upvoted for legit concerns - I just hope any potential answer won't be used in illegal actions.

Comment: "How to check if bootloader is effective-locked?" → `fastboot oem device-info` should tell you ([this Xiaomi thread](http://en.miui.com/thread-279195-1-1.html) might give you more details, though it's for the Xiaomi Mi 5/Pro). And congrats to your gained rep, you now can enter [our chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25/android-enthusiasts) so extensive "discussion" in comments can be avoided. Not many people in there at the moment, though; but dropping a question and having some patience usually helps :)

Comment: Thanks for answer @Izzy (I am learning about ADB and Fastboot, this days, searching for a hack, I am newbie on Android context but I am a faster-deep-learner) in the meanwhile, maybe I learn something because of this. I will see that link and continue my research about this matter (from a "own smartphone" perspective, of course) the right of owners to recover "own data" beyond the "common problem" ("the Righteous pay the price of Sinners", idiom I don't know if exists on English, as I am spanish speaker. About the levels rep etc (I am a newbie on StackExchange :D) thanks for comment and help.

Comment: @AndyYan Thanks for understanding (this is a complex topic), I have background on Data-recovery and IT-Forensics (I could access data directly via Hardware) even if that implies a JTAG-like dump (but I prefer, first try a "software method", the nature of personal info implies I won't hire a "specialist", only a specific "how to". I post on official MIUI forums, I will see if that get some answers. – TarekJor 14 mins ago   delete

Comment: BTW, I agree with the "extensive discussion in comments" problem, sorry about that :)  (from now on I will use chat). Now I am on this step:  first get official support from OEM Xiaomi, even if they need to use their propietary tools, but that has a problem about "confidential data" on Data Recovery (I will try to avoid low level JTAG-like dump, as possible), thanks for all your answers. The key thing is, if there is no-exploit, then only OEM has the solution, and as the "device owner" this need a proper special fix, but it is possible.